# CSS help - make image in element exceed the top border

Tags: html, css

I am working with a PSD design at the moment which has part of the company logo sitting above a header element, and part of it contained with in it. The logo partially exceeds the top border.

Something like this: http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/5589/headerrc.png with the solid filled square being the logo that needs to exceed the border.

I'm wondering what the best way to do this in the most accessible way is; I know I can slice it all up as images, but I'd prefer to use HTML elements to build the display.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Is the border an actual html border or is it an background image.  Asking mainly because the image mockup had non-square corners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't explain your html setup at all, so i can only suggest things very broadly, its difficult to know which would be more appropriate.

```
margin-top: -30px;
```

alternatively:

```
position: relative;  
top: -30px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a negative margin within your CSS to push the logo up:

```
#logo { margin-top: -20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could position it absolutely and set the coordinates directly, and still keep it centered if you need to.  Here's a quick example:

```
   #header {
       margin-top: 30px;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100px;
       position: relative;
   }

   #logo {
       left: 50%;
       margin-left: 100px;
       top: 10px;
       height: 50px;
       width: 50px;
       position: absolute;
   }
```

You can set the margin-left to any value to position it that distance from the center.  As long as the 'top' of #logo is less than the 'margin-top' of #header, it will sit above the header.